# Proof of Integer Remainder Summation Conjecture

Tags: number-theory

If we select any finite subset of the naturals:

$$\mathcal H={\{h_k}\}_{k=1..N} \subset \mathbb N \land N \gt 1$$

Edit as the first answerer has shown my lower bound for $N$ does not hold and I revise to:

$$\mathcal H={\{h_k}\}_{k=1..N} \subset \mathbb N \land N \gt 3$$

And define the following arithmetic functions:

$$f(n,N)=\sum _{k=1}^{N} \operatorname{irem} \left( h_{{k}}-n+1,n \right)\tag{1a}$$

$$g(n,N)=\sum _{k=1}^{N}\operatorname{irem} \left( h_{{k}}-1,n \right)\tag{1b}$$

where $\operatorname{irem}(n,m)$ is the integer remainder of the division of $n$ by $m$.

We have for **even** $n \gt 3$:

$$\max(f(n,N),g(n,N))\equiv\min(f(n,N),g(n,N))\pmod 2\tag{2a}$$

Proving this has not been as straight forward, however based on the knowledge of both the maximum and minimum being either odd or even, $(2a)$ implies:

$$\max(f(n,N),g(n,N))\equiv 0\pmod 2 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \min(f(n,N),g(n,N))\equiv 0\pmod 2 \tag{3a}$$

$$\max(f(n,N),g(n,N)) \not\equiv 0\pmod 2 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow \min(f(n,N),g(n,N))\not\equiv 0\pmod 2 \tag{3b}$$

Intuitively I have been expecting [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) to be relevant to the proof of $(2a)$ , but have not made any progress yet.

Defining a third function:

$$u(n,N)=\sum _{k=1}^{N}\operatorname{irem} \left( h_{{k}}+1,n \right)\tag{3b}$$

We have for **odd** or **even** $n \gt 2$:

$$\max(f(n,N),u(n,N))\equiv\min(f(n,N),u(n,N))\pmod 2\tag{2b}$$

And for **even** $n \gt 3$:

$$\max(u(n,N),g(n,N))\equiv\min(u(n,N),g(n,N))\pmod 2\tag{2c}$$

My final edit, and a clarification of what my question actually is, we generalize the functions as follows:

$$f(n,N)=\sum _{k=1}^{N} \operatorname{irem} \left( h_{{k}}+\alpha_n,n \right)\tag{4a}$$
$$g(n,N)=\sum _{k=1}^{N} \operatorname{irem} \left( h_{{k}}+\beta_n,n \right)\tag{4b}$$

And in order for the congruence relation:

$$\max(f(n,N),g(n,N))\equiv\min(f(n,N),g(n,N))\pmod 2\tag{4c}$$

To hold for all $n \gt 1$, I have found that the values denoted alpha and beta can be elements of the following subset, the super set of which I seek to establish the cardinality of:

$${\{\alpha_n,\beta_n}\} \in {\{{\{-n,n}\},{\{1-n,1}\},{\{n-1,-1}\},{\{-1,-(n+1)}\},{\{1,n+1}\},{\{0,n}\},{\{0,-n}\}}\}\tag{4d}$$

One rule that appears to hold is:

$$\alpha_n=-\beta_n \Rightarrow f(n,N)=g(n,N)\tag{5a}$$
And so the nature of this superset for the final lemma should be considered focal point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems wrong. Take $N=n=3$, $h_1=6,h_2=9,h_3=12$: then $f(n,N)=3$, $g(n,N)=6$.

Comment: but that would be a singleton with $N=1$ which is excluded by the condition $N \gt 1$

Comment: I was referring to a finite set not a multiset

Comment: Okay. I edited.

Comment: nice this will help any counter examples  with $N \gt 3$ you know of?

Comment: It seems a bit strange for me to repost a separate question with the lower bound for $N$ corrected but if there is a counter example of larger cardinality I suppose I'll just have to go with $h_k$ restricted to the primes

Comment: sorry $n \gt 3$

Comment: I have found large number of counter examples to the original statement I made now, of all values of $N$ for $n \leq 3$, I guess I get what I deserve there for being lazy lol

Comment: Sorry huge mistake on my part I was only considering even $n$.